# powershell get-aduser specific date range

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this.
I am writing a program that will look back at a certain date range and then return the values that I specify in a get-aduser cmdlet

The code I have thus far is here:

```
    $grabDate = Read-Host 'enter how many days back you want to search'
$date = Get-Date
$desiredDate = $date.AddDays(- $grabDate)
Write-Host $desiredDate 'to' $date 'is your search range'
Pause

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, LastLogonDate | Where-Object { $date.AddDays(- $grabDate) } | Select-Object name, LastLogonDate
```

I know that this is not the cleanest code and there are some redundant steps my main focus is on the line:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, LastLogonDate | Where-Object { $date.AddDays(- $grabDate) } | Select-Object name, LastLogonDate
```

when I enter 30 days to search back, I am getting strange entries from 2016, does anyone see anything strange with my code?

Comment: Your Where should compare two dates not just check there **is** a date. A simple comparison doesn't need a {script block} so `Where-Object LastLogonDate -gt $desiredDate |`

Comment: I wrote a custom implementation in a module for something similar. Depending on your needs, you may also want to validate the date or dates supplied, and the format of the object supplied depending on CurrentCulture

Comment: Thank you both for the replies I am going to run with the information given and see if I can get some good data back

Comment: Not quite sure whether you want the users who *have* logged on in the last `n` days or users who *haven't* logged on in the last `n` days. I answered assuming the latter, but I can change it up if I got your intent backwards.

Comment: DOOOOD @LotPings you are the man! thank you so much this works.

Comment: I still highly suggest you don't blindly grab all `ADUser` objects and process them. This can be a costly operation. It is not needed if you use the filter parameter to filter on specific properties.

Comment: it would be nice in the final revision of the app to give an option to search users how have vs have not logged in @BendertheGreatest

Comment: @BendertheGreatest currently it is searching last logon which is what my boss asked for LOL. I am just working on the guts right now I plan to make a pretty app down the road with powershell studio. Last logon is what was asked for so thats what I am doing but additional functionality would be cool

Comment: I flipped the logic in the filter in my answer to grab accounts logged on within the last specified number of days

Answer (score 1):

No need for the pipeline here - just use a little simple math, a conversion from `string` to `int`, and use the `-Filter` parameter as it was designed.

Set `$grabDate` like this, so you get an actual `int` value, not a string

```
# Convert Read-Host input to an integer, and multiply by -1 to get the negative value
$grabDate = [Convert]::ToInt32( (Read-Host 'enter how many days back you want to search' ) ) * -1
```

Then call `Get-ADUser` with the following `-Filter` parameter:

```
# Use the filter to return only the users who haven't logged on in the
# last $grabDate days
Get-ADUser -Filter "LastLogonDate -ge '$((Get-Date).AddDays( $grabDate ))'"
```

This way, you only return the ADUsers you care about and you don't have to process the list of users a second time. Using `-Filter *` can be a costly operation, especially in larger AD environments.

Comment: I'd interpret `How many days back` as looking for newer LogonDates so it should be `-gt` or `-ge` then.

Comment: Done. Simple switch flip from `-lt` to `-ge`

Comment: what version of powershell did you write your get-aduser line in? I am unable to execute this code

Comment: I am getting the following debug:

Comment: I think I will have to import the active directory module for this to work

Comment: debug was too long for comment

Comment: I need to search the entire directory for an audit so I have: 

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,LastLogonDate,Department -ge $((Get-Date).AddDays($grabDate))

Comment: You are still searching the entire directory, just returning only the accounts that match your parameters. Based on your commands and question you only care about accounts where the last logon dates are within the last `$grabDate` days. And your command in the last comment is wrong, you are using `-ge` in the wrong place. Should look like `Get-ADUser -Filter "LastLogonDate -ge '$((Get-Date).AddDays($grabDate))'" -Properties Name,LastLogonDate,Department`

Comment: this is giving me quite a bit of hastle I have started from scratch trying to go off of this guide: https://www.adaxes.com/blog/cleanup-active-directory-with-powershell.html

Comment: okay so @BendertheGreatest I am running that line of code and I am getting weird data with a | export-csv -path '\\sharelocation' on the end of it it is giving way more info than i want

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I think I got it 
Get-ADUser -Filter "LastLogonDate -ge '$((Get-Date).AddDays($grabDate))'" -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, Department | Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate, Department | Export-Csv -Path '\\freshData.csv'

Comment: Yeah, there are default properties that are always returned on an `ADObject`, and in fact they never need to be specified in `-Properties`. TO curate what gets exported, you are correct to use `Select Object` to pick the properties you want to pipe into `Export-Csv`

Comment: @BendertheGreatest cool cool can you explain to me why there are quotes around "LastLogonDate -ge '$((Get-Date).AddDays($grabDate))'" my powershell studio ide is thinking its all a comment

Comment: Yes, because the `-Filter` parameter takes a string. Don't know why your IDE thinks it's a comment though. If you run that code on a server with the AD cmdlets available you should be able to see it work (just make sure `$grabDate` is set like I have in my answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Set the number of days since last logon
$DaysInactive = 90
$InactiveDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

#-------------------------------
# FIND INACTIVE USERS
#-------------------------------
# Below are four options to find inactive users. Select the one that is most appropriate for your requirements:

# Get AD Users that haven't logged on in xx days
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter { LastLogonDate -lt $InactiveDate -and Enabled -eq $true } -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object @{ Name="Username"; Expression={$_.SamAccountName} }, Name, LastLogonDate, DistinguishedName
```

Comment: this appears to work perfectly, however I need a user to specify a date range and when I tweak that first part using the advice in this thread - it does not search correctly

Comment: actually forget this - I am getting results from 2004 - reverting back to the old version of doing things and using the above posted help from bender